# Is The 70-515 MCTS Training Kit Wrong on a ASP.NET Health Monitoring question?

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

In my book, "MCTS SElf-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-515): Web Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4", on page 418 there is the following question:

> You want to configure ASP.NET health
> monitoring to log information every
> time a user fails to log on to the
> server.  Which web event class should
> you use?
>
> - A.  WebRequestEvent
> - B.  WebAuditEvent
> - C.  WebApplicationLifetimeEvent
> - D.  WebAuthenticationSuccessAuditEvent

The answer, according to the book is **D**.  However, according to the book, WebAuthenticationSuccessAuditEvent is

> "Used to provide information when a
> successful user authentication occurs
> on the site"

.  I'm thinking that maybe the book meant to say that the WebAuthenticationFailureAuditEvent class should be used, which is

> "Used to provide information when a
> failed attempt at user authentication
> occurs on the site.

Am I correct in believing that the book is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The book is wrong.